# How do I run OpenCover in TeamCity 2017.2?

Tags: teamcity, opencover

I am running TeamCity 2017.2 and have downloaded and installed the OpenCover plugin from https://github.com/mindriven/TeamCity-OpenCoverRunner. On the plugins page in TeamCity I can OpenCoverRunner is installed, but I'm not seeing a reference to it anywhere when I am configuring my build. TeamCity-OpenCoverRunner's wiki page displays some screenshots depicting the runner as having it's own build step configuration page, but I'm not seeing that in my TeamCity instance. I've rebooted the server (not just restarted the TeamCity service) post-install to ensure all plug-ins were loaded properly. Am I doing something wrong?